# AS3 - Flash 11 and Fullscreening

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I am having a problem setting my program to run in full screen.

I'm creating a win projector in flash builder 4.5 (with flash 11.5) and I've tried using fscommands to do it and I just end up with a black screen... Is there a preferred way to set it to run in full screen from flash builder?

```
fscommand("fullscreen","true");
fscommand("allowscale","false");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this simple code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
 applicationComplete="init();">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        import flash.display.StageDisplayState;

        private function init():void{

            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

        }


        ]]>
    </mx:Script>


</mx:Application>
```

Also in the HTML file in which this SWF file is placed add the following to the Flash SWF Object:

```
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
```

Hope that works!